# How to return values from multidimensional array in listview (VBA)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I tried to solve my problem as follows:

```
intFirstIdx = UBound(arrDetailInfo, 1)
intSecIdx = UBound(arrDetailInfo, 2)

With Me.lvDetaillist
    With .ColumnHeaders
        .Clear
        .Add , , "#", 20
        .Add , , "ID", 50
        .Add , , "Assets", 50
        .Add , , "Day Count", 50
        .Add , , "Result", 150
    End With
    .ListItems.Clear
End With

cnt = 1
With Me.lvDetaillist
    For i = 0 To intFirstIdx
        Set li = .ListItems.Add(, , cnt)
        For k = 0 To intSecIdx
            li.SubItems(cnt) = arrDetailInfo(i, k)
        Next k
        cnt = cnt + 1
    Next i
End With
```

And here is my Array with content:

[image]

Do anyone knows an approach how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `li.SubItems(cnt) = arrDetailInfo(i, k)`

Try this instead:

```
li.SubItems(k+1) = arrDetailInfo(i, k)
```

You could do it without those counters `cnt` and `bytRowCnt`:

```
With Me.lvDetaillist
    For i = 0 To intFirstIdx
        Set li = .ListItems.Add(, , i+1)
        For k = 0 To intSecIdx
            li.SubItems(k+1) = arrDetailInfo(i, k)
        Next k
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thanks it also was helpful :) a bit smaller than my code! :)

Comment: @Yuro yeah. Funny thing you found your own solution at the same minute I was posting my answer (first part). Glad to know it was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this as follows:

```
intFirstIdx = UBound(arrDetailInfo, 2)
intSecIdx = UBound(arrDetailInfo, 1)

bytRowCnt = 1
With Me.lvDetaillist
    For i = 0 To intFirstIdx
        Set li = .ListItems.Add(, , bytRowCnt)

        cnt = 1
        For k = 0 To intSecIdx
            li.SubItems(cnt) = arrDetailInfo(k, i)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        Next k
        bytRowCnt = bytRowCnt + 1
    Next i
End With
```

And it works very great :)

Comment: You dont need those additional counters anyway, `i` and `k` should suffice. See my answer below :)